# Application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions or applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I would like to know how I can provide the way to user for downloading the content from server.

If the user subscribes for one month, I want to deliver them a new content (songs) every day. But I am not sure how to work on this.

Do I need to call the webservice in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or in the - `(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {`

Which one should I use for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning on starting a new connection when the app launches, then you'll want to use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

However, `applicationDidBecomeActive` is better suited for resuming a download that you paused when your application was backgrounded. Starting the download here COULD also be acceptable too.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```